# how to get a dict of instance fields with in a class definition in python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, instance-variables

For `functions`, the `locals()` method return the local variables inside the `function`
eg:

```
>>> def f():
...  x=5
...  y=6
...  return locals()
... 
>>> f()
{'y': 6, 'x': 5}
>>>
```

I am looking for something similar in a `class`.

```
>>> class c(object):
...     x=5
...     y=6
...     def local(self):
...       dict={}
...       dict['x']=self.x
...       dict['y']=self.y
...       return dict
... 
>>> v=c()
>>> v.local()
{'y': 6, 'x': 5}
```

but I want to do this in `multiple classes` and I have lot of `fields` defined with in a `class`. so I am wondering if there is a `built-in method` that returns a `dict of all the instance attributes`

Actually I am using this in `Django`, where i want to pass the instance fields to a `re-direct url` that accepts them as `key-word arguements`

EDIT:
I want to get a dict of instance attributes with in the class itself.
I do not want to make an instance to the get dict out.

I tried this out:

```
>>> class c(object):
...    x=5
...    y=10
...    def local(self):
...      return c.__dict__
... 
>>> v=c()
>>> v.local()
<dictproxy object at 0x10f640ef8>
>>>
```

It is not returning a dictionary of key-value of fields and its values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can access the instance's dictionary of objects as:

```
v.__dict__
```

or the class's at

```
c.__dict__
```

Or, as Chiel92 points out, using `vars(c)`/`vars(v)`.

You can make this a class method:

```
class c:

    x=2
    y=5

    @classmethod
    def attrs(cls):
        return vars(cls)
```

But `c.attrs()` seems no better than `c.__dict__` or `vars(c)`.

Note that you shouldn't call your own dictionaries `dict`, as this shadows the Python built-in.

Comment: I want to get the defined attributes within the class. i.e I do not want to make an instance. sorry, I will make this clear in the question